# jquery-loadmask: where should i call unmask()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mask

i want to use [jquery-loadmask](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) plugin to mask a form while the form data is transmited (I have used AJAX to call the action that store the data in the db).

To mask the form i'm using this:

```
    $('#form').submit(function () {

           form_data = $.param($(this).serializeArray());

           $.ajax({

               url: "<?php echo url_for('profile/index') ?>",

               type: "POST",

               data: form_data,

           });


           $("form").mask("Loading...");



           return false;

    });
```

But where should i call unmask() ?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unmask in your `success` callback (when the server comes back with data), like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "<?php echo url_for('profile/index') ?>",
   type: "POST",
   data: form_data,
   success: function() { $("form").unmask(); }
});
```

Or, the shorter [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) format:

```
$.post("<?php echo url_for('profile/index') ?>", form_data, function() {
  $("form").unmask();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a success or error handler:

```
$.ajax({

           url: "<?php echo url_for('profile/index') ?>",

           type: "POST",

           data: form_data,
```

**success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { $("form").unmask(); }**

```
       });
```

Comment: ooh, that is ugly - but you get the gist?